# Amazon Athena unable to convert date to timestamp in query

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

I would like to convert date value to timestamp format using Amazon Athena Query and used below function to convert ,able to convert some of the dates into timestamp format but not working for some of the date values ,Please find below example

```
date_parse('10/20/1977','%m/%d/%Y') output is 1977-10-20 00:00:00:000
```

But for below type of dates showing error:

```
date_parse('02/29/1977''%m/%d/%Y') output is 

cannot parse "02/29/1977":value 29 for dayOfMonth must be in range [1-28]
```

Answer (score 0):

1977 (Gregorian calendar) was not a leap year, so there were no 29th of February - there were only [28](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?year=1977&country=1) days. So you need to fix the data.